# chunk list in groups with custom sort in dart

Tags: dart

Supposed that I have a List integers and I need this list to chunks into 4 lists to be a list of lists of integer with very custom sort,
**
I hope this image explain my current list and what I want **

`var myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34, 35,36];`

what I want

```
var myList = [
[1,2,3,7,8,9, 13,14,15],
[4,5,6,10,11,12,16,17,18],
[19,20,21, 25,26,27, 31,32,33],
[22,23,24, 28,29,30, 34,35,36],
];
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the sorting in this question? Looks more like you have a given data structure in form of a list of integers and what it to be converted into a specific other kind of data structure. Does your input always have the same amount of numbers? And do you always want to split this input into this form as specified?

Comment: I would call this "reshaping" (of multidimensional arrays or, in Dart terms, nested lists) rather than "sorting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see where "very custom sort" comes into play here. For me, it looks like you have a fixed size input and you want to split this input up into a very specific data structure.

If that is the case, I think a simple solution would be the following:

```dart
void main() {
  final List<int> input = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, //
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, //
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, //
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, //
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, //
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, //
  ];

  List<List<int>> result = convert(input);

  result.forEach(print);
  // [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15]
  // [4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18]
  // [19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27, 31, 32, 33]
  // [22, 23, 24, 28, 29, 30, 34, 35, 36]
}

List<List<int>> convert(List<int> i) => i.length == 36
    ? [
        [
          i[00], i[01], i[02], //
          i[06], i[07], i[08], //
          i[12], i[13], i[14], //
        ],
        [
          i[03], i[04], i[05], //
          i[09], i[10], i[11], //
          i[15], i[16], i[17], //
        ],
        [
          i[18], i[19], i[20], //
          i[24], i[25], i[26], //
          i[30], i[31], i[32], //
        ],
        [
          i[21], i[22], i[23], //
          i[27], i[28], i[29], //
          i[33], i[34], i[35], //
        ],
      ]
    : throw Exception('Input list contains ${i.length} '
        'elements but must contain 36!');
```

You could argue it would take fewer lines of code to make some loops that does this. But I think the code makes it rather clear what it actually does when it comes to how data is being mapped.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *generalize*, say:
Given a list with *N*×*M* elements, representing an *N*-by-*M* matrix,
convert it to lists representing the four quadrants of the matrix.

Then first to decide what happens if the side lengths are odd numbers.
Let's say we make the second part larger (because rounding is easier that way).

Then it would be:

```dart
// values is matrix where first [n] values is the first row.
List<List<T>> splitMatrix<T>(int n, int m, List<T> values) {
  assert(values.length == n * m);
  var halfN = n ~/ 2;
  var halfM = m ~/ 2;
  List<T> chunk(startN, endN, startM, endM) => [
    for (var i = startM; i < endM; i++) 
      for (var j = startN;j < endN; j++) 
        values[i * n + j]
  ];
  return [
    chunk(0, halfN, 0, halfM),
    chunk(halfN, n, 0, halfM),
    chunk(0, halfN, halfM, m),
    chunk(halfN, n, halfM, m),
  ];
}
```

This works as:

```dart
final List<int> input = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, //
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, //
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, //
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, //
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, //
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, //
  ];
var quadrants = splitMatrix<int>(6, 6, input);
print(quadrants.join("\n"));
```

which prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15]
[4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27, 31, 32, 33]
[22, 23, 24, 28, 29, 30, 34, 35, 36]
```

as expected.